# Why can't I use my nestjs custom decorator in a constructor?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to create a custom decorator to return tenant information. I have the following code:

```
export type TenantInfo = {
    token: string
    id: string
}

export const TenantInfo = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext): TenantInfo => {
      // todo use context to get from auth header
      return { id: '1', token: 'todo' }
  },
);
```

Now i register it in the tenant service:

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class TenantService {
  private readonly _tenantInfo: TenantInfo;

  constructor(
    @TenantId() tenantInfo: TenantInfo,
  ) {
    this._tenantInfo = tenantInfo;
    logger.log(`Received GRPC message from tenant id ${tenantInfo.id}`);
  }
}
```

And when I run my code it says:

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TenantService (?).
> Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in
> the TenantModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If Object is a provider, is it part of the current TenantModule?
> - If Object is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TenantModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing Object */ ]

I'm not sure how to get around this. It's saying register it in the module but I get errors if I try putting TenantInfo in the providers array...

> Type '(...dataOrPipes: unknown[]) => ParameterDecorator' is not
> assignable to type 'Provider'

How do you do this? All I want is to get some details from the request context.

Comment: Despite the fact that you cannot use parameter decorator inside a class constructor, you only can fetch request information from controllers not services. So move decorator to the controller method.

Comment: How come this works: @Inject(REQUEST) protected request: RequestContextHost, within a service?

Comment: That's for injecting a dependency into class constructor which is different from what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there anyway to inject the executioncontext?

Comment: on the method level yes, on the whole class level no

Answer (score 1):

`createParamDecorator` only creates decorators that work for route handlers (Controllers, Resolvers, or Gateways). For something that can be injected at the constructor level of a service you can either inject the request, via `@Inject(REQUEST)`, or you can create a custom request scoped provider and custom decorator like so:

```js
export const InjectTenantId = () => Inject('TENANTID');

export const tenantIdProvider = {
  provide: 'TENANTID',
  inject: [REQUEST],
  scope: Scope.REQUEST,
  useFactory: (request) => getTenantIdFromRequest(request)
}
```

And now in your constructor you can do `@InjectTenantId() private readonly tenantInfo: TenantInfo`.

Comment: can you solve my problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73193534/nestjs-mock-i18n-and-request-in-jest-service