# nestjs mock i18n and request in jest service

Tags: jestjs, mocking, nestjs

I have a controller like this

```
async create(@Body() dto: myDTO,@Req() request, @I18n() i18n?: I18nContext): Promise<MyEntity> 
{
   return this.Myservice.create(dto, request, i18n);
}
```

and service like this:

```
async create(dto: CreateApplicationDTO,  request?, i18n?): Promise<Application> {
     const MyEntity= this.repository.create(dto);
     request.message = i18n.t('common.added_successful');
     return this.repository.save(MyEntity);
}
```

and service.spec file this :

```
it('check number of created applications', async () => {
     await service.create(myDto);
     expect(await service.findAll()).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

When I start test show me this error

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'message')
> ```

```
  41 |             return this.repository.save(newApplication);
  42 |         } catch (e) {
> 43 |             return request.message = e.message;
     |                                   ^
  44 |         }
  45 |
  46 |     }
```

I know I should send `request` and `i18n` to service but I don't know how mock them and send them to service in my `spec` file

Answer (score 1):

You've set `request` to be optional but set a property on it regardless if it is populated or not. You need to make sure that `request` has a value before you try to assign to it. For simplicity sake, because you don't give it a type, it could just be `{}` and then `{}.message =`  will be valid.

As for `i18n` in your `create` method you use the object method `t` so you need the mock to have a `t` method. Something like `{ t: jest.fn(() => 'some value') }` should be enough to get the test going with a mock.

Having stronger typings will help you though, even if it means it is harder to make mocks. You could use a tool like [`@golevelup/ts-jest`](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/testing) can be used to create full mocks off of types alone

Comment: I'm new in nest and jest. can you write sample code

Comment: [How about I link you to a repo that has a bunch of Nest testing examples instead](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)